# Can inotify be used to detect file existence checks?

Tags: linux, inotify

I am trying to use `inotifywait` to detect when a process checks for the existence of a file, but the event is not captured.

For example, this program checks if /tmp/test exists:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    int main() {
        if (access("/tmp/test", F_OK) == 0) {
            printf("yes");
        } else {
            printf("no");
        }
    }
```

Compile with:

```
    gcc -o testfileexists testfileexists.c
```

Now run inotifywait to monitor /tmp:

```
    inotifywait -r -m -c /tmp
```

Then run testfileexists to check if /tmp/test exists:

```
    ./testfileexists
```

No output is displayed from `inotifywait`.

Is there a way to capture file existence checks that occur (via `access()` or `stat()`, or bash `[ -f` for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `access(/tmp/test)` does not create, delete, or modify a file, so there are no events for `inotifywait` to capture.

Similarly, you can't use inotify to capture someone's attempt to open a file that doesn't exist: trying to `cat /tmp/test`, if `/tmp/test` doesn't exist, doesn't generate any filesystem events, either.

---

Depending on what you're trying to do, there are ways to capture this access.  For example, if you run the target code under control of `strace`, you can log the check:

```
$ strace -e trace=access ./checkfile
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/tmp/test", F_OK)               = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
no+++ exited with 0 +++
```

You can perform similar monitoring using tools like `perf trace`.